# How to Set a Background Color to Sidebar Position to Span Full Page Length and to Screen's Edge on Right Side

Tags: css

The sidebar in question can be seen here in light blue color: http://www.comparayacierta.es/mejores-productos-de-hogar/mejor-centro-de-planchado

I know I need to use some sort of negative margins/padding, but I can't seem to get it right. It goes right past the end of the page and into the website's footer. I also cannot get it to go to the edge of the screen on the right without displacing the module that's in the siderbar.

Here is the code I have at present:

```
.relbar {
background-color: #ccebff;
 margin: 0 0 -2000rem;
padding: 1rem 0 2000rem;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the details of the sidebar:

```
 background-color:
rgb(204, 235, 255)
;
box-sizing:
border-box
;
color:
rgb(136, 136, 136)
;
display:
block
;
font-family:
roboto, Helvetica, Tahoma, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif
;
font-size:
16px
;
font-weight:
normal
;
height:
32570px
;
line-height:
24px
;
list-style-image:
none
;
list-style-position:
outside
;
list-style-type:
none
;
margin-bottom:
-32000px
;
margin-left:
0px
;
margin-right:
0px
;
margin-top:
0px
;
padding-bottom:
32000px
;
padding-left:
0px
;
padding-right:
0px
;
padding-top:
16px
;
width:
192px
;
-webkit-font-smoothing:
antialiased
```

Comment: can You add a full working code in snippet?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean Maciej. Sorry if I'm being dumb here. The css I have to try and set the background is listed above. What do you mean by "full working code snippet"?

Comment: it will be more clearly when u past Your code html and css for example there fiddle.jshell.net/

Comment: then will be easier to help You

Comment: I'm not sure where I can take that code from? I just wrote the CSS I listed above.

Comment: I genuinely don't know how I can show the problem more clearly or display code so that it can be reproduced. The background set for the module position in quest break into the module position outside of it. If I could attach a screenshot it would clearly show it. I don't know what code I can paste here that makes it clear.

Comment: it will be clear when You copy all of your code :)

Comment: Still don't follow..All of the code from my whole site? The only code I produced in relation to this problem is listed above.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Set a Background Color to Sidebar Position to Span Full Page Length and to Screen's Edge on Right Side

Use a pseudo-element and remove all the extra margins & padding etc.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.grid-75 {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  background: pink;
}
.grid-25 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background: lightblue;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.sidebar {
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-75"></div>
  <div class="grid-25 sidebar">I'm the sidebar content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie. I'm not sure I even know how to implement your answer though unfortunately ha.